# Removing the zoom option for the current page in IE

Tags: activex, internet-explorer

I implemented an ActiveX control that gets loaded when a tiff file is detected. 
I want to remove the IE Zoom option for the current page, the zooming will be handled by the activex itself.

From IServiceProvider I can get a pointer to IWebBrowser2, but the only thing I can do there is to query the status of the zoom command.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Cristian

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this in an existing browser window. You used to be able to hide the whole status bar if you opened a popup window, but that is not allowed now because of phishing concerns.

Comment: Adobe PDF plugin does it (zoom is disabled on the page where the pdf file is shown, zoom is enabled on any other page), I assume it must be a way